# Simpler argument that embedded submanifold has unique smooth structure

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a embedding of differentiable manifolds. Then there is a unique manifold structure on $S:=f(X)$ such that the inclusion map $S \hookrightarrow Y$ is a diffeomorphism.

In Lee's book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", he argues in Theorem 5.21 as follows: Suppose $\tilde{S}$ were some other smooth manifold structure on $S$ such that the inclusion $\tilde{i}: \tilde{S} \hookrightarrow Y$ is an embedding. Then the restricted map $\tilde{i}:\tilde{S} \to S$ is a smooth map. Since $\tilde{i}: S\to Y$ has injective derivative maps, so does $\tilde{i}:\tilde{S} \to S$. **But then $\tilde{i}:\tilde{S} \to S$ is a bijective immersion, so is a diffeomorphism**. The part in bold follows from what he calls the "Global Rank Theorem" (his Theorem 4.14). This theorem uses the Baire Category Theorem and relies on $\tilde{S}$ being second-countable.

Is there any simplification of this argument? Using the BCT feels a little like taking a sledgehammer to a walnut. If one knows about homology, then we can argue as follows: $\tilde{i}: \tilde{S} \to Y$ is a homeomorphism onto its image $S$ so (since $\mathbb{R}^n \not \cong \mathbb{R}^m$ for $n\neq m$ by homology) $\tilde{S},S$ have the same dimension, whence $d_x\tilde{i}$ is bijective for all $x\in \tilde{S}$. Then $\tilde{i}$ is a bijective local diffeomorphism so is a diffeomorphism.

However, now we are reliant on the machinery of homology instead. Is there any truly elementary argument, which is only "smooth manifolds"-y in nature?

Comment: You can show with the inverse function theorem that any smooth bijective map whose differential is an isomorphism of tangent spaces at each point is a diffeomorphism. That might help.

Comment: @Chris that's exactly the fact I've used in my alternative argument when I say "Then $\tilde{i}$ is a bijective local differmorphism so is a diffeomorphism". The problem is that to get the bijectivity on the tangent spaces, you need to know that $S,\tilde{S}$ have the same dimension! If I want to identify the dimension from the topology on $S$, then I need to know about homology

Comment: Ah I see. Can’t you assume the existence of an exotics smooth structure on $\tilde{S}$ and from there deduce it has the same dimension though?

Comment: @Chris Possibly you could do it that way too, but that's exactly the sort of argument I'm asking for in this question

Comment: I see. I'll see if I can come up with something.